# Null response Xamarin android application using web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin.android

Hi I am just learning Xamarin android development and I just want to CRUD operation but I am stuck that I am unable to get any response from webapi. I have tested my api using SOAPUI and response is ok from that.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateEmpAttandance(string value)
{
    if (value != "1234")
    {
        string json = @"{ data: 'Emp Code is not valid.'}";
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(jObject.ToString(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return response;

    }
    else
    {
        string json = @"{ data: 'data save sucessfully.'}";
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(jObject.ToString(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return response;


    }
}
```

this is api code and below is my android application code but I am getting null response exception.

```
  public async Task SaveTodoItemAsync(string EmpCode)
    {
        try
        {
            string url = "http://192.168.1.9/attandanceapi/api/attandance?value=12132";

            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url));
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(EmpCode);
            var content = new StringContent(EmpCode, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

            var responses = response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            var w = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you access http://192.168.1.9/attandanceapi/api/attandance?value=12132 via browser on device?

Comment: yes, response is as per requirement

Comment: seems like your api needs post request and you are giving get request from android

Comment: @Yogesh , It is post request response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

Answer (score 0):

I think we have problem here. You are trying to create content from string not from Json.

```
var content = new StringContent(EmpCode, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

try this:

```
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Edit:

I cannot see your default headers so if you don't have them - just add.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
```